# Viewport and Camera setting

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, camera, viewport

For my first game in LibGDX and Android I got a Problem:

I have a background picture which is 2560px * 720px. The screen is 1280 * 720. How do I have to set the viewport and camera in order to get the following result: The picture is fited in height and shows the first 1280px in width.

I tried so many things and it really confused me.

**Gamescreen.java**

```
package com.joelbrun.jetskirider.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;

public class Gamescreen implements Screen {


    public Texture jetski, wave, background;
    public SpriteBatch batch;
    public OrthographicCamera camera;
    public Label score;
    public static final int GAMESCREEN_WIDTH = 1920;
    public static final int GAMESCREEN_HEIGHT = 720;
    public static final int OBSTACLE_TYPES = 5;

    Viewport viewport;
    private Texture[] texture;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        texture = new Texture[OBSTACLE_TYPES];
        for (int i=0; i<OBSTACLE_TYPES; i++){
            texture[i] = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("game/obstacles/obstacle" + Integer.toString(i+1)+".png"));
        }
        background = new Texture("game/background.png");
        jetski = new Texture("game/jetski.png");
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/(float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();

        viewport = new FitViewport(GAMESCREEN_WIDTH, GAMESCREEN_HEIGHT);
        viewport.apply();
        camera.position.set(GAMESCREEN_WIDTH / 2, GAMESCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
        //camera.position.set(0,0,0);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(background, 0, 0, 5119, 720);
        batch.draw(jetski, background.getWidth()/2, background.getHeight()/2,128,128);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
        camera.position.set(GAMESCREEN_WIDTH / 2, GAMESCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        background.dispose();
        jetski.dispose();
        wave.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @jzx Updated...

Comment: Why are you modifying GAMESCREEN_WIDTH and HEIGHT before passing it to the viewport? They need to be the same in viewport as to what you set your background-sprites height to. just leave that aspect ratio stuff away.

Comment: @VaTTeRGeR I updated the code and it still does only show a black screen

Comment: You should have left your GAMESCREEN_W/H at 16 and 9. You just need to draw in world coordinates since you have applied your cameras projection matrix to your batch. Try batch.draw(background, 0, 0, 32, GAMESCREEN_HEIGHT); and change the stuff back to world coordinates. You could also upload the project to look at and try it out. (oh and change the 32 to something dynamically calculated or so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you change these parts in `show()`:

```
viewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.fillY, GAMESCREEN_WIDTH, GAMESCREEN_HEIGHT, camera = new OrthographicCamera());
```

and add a resize method:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    int SCREEN_WIDTH = width;
    int SCREEN_HEIGHT = height;

    viewport.setWorldSize(GAMESCREEN_WIDTH, GAMESCREEN_HEIGHT);
    viewport.update(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,true);
}
```

It's important, that you set your Sprites height to `GAMESCREEN_HEIGHT` and you may need to move around your `camera` a bit but that shouldn't be that hard.

```
private void moveView(Vector3 v) {
    camera.translate(v);
    camera.update();
}
```

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to vote up, but thanks a lot :D

Comment: No problem, does it work now?

Comment: yes! All perfect